# how to replace a string stored in a regular expression extractor variable and used in subsequent request in jmeter?

Tags: regex, jmeter, extractor

I have response data captured in a variable in  regular expression extractor like

```
SAMLResponse" value="PHNhbWxwOlJlc3BvbnNlIHhtbG5zOnNhbWxwPSJ1cm46b2FzaXM6bmFtZXM6dGM6U0FNTDoyLjA6&#xd;&#xa;cHJvdG9jb2wiIElEPSJzMmYx ...
```

In the subsequent request it goes as :

```
SAMLResponse="PHNhbWxwOlJlc3BvbnNlIHhtbG5zOnNhbWxwPSJ1cm46b2FzaXM6bmFtZXM6dGM6U0FNTDoyLjA6%0D%0AcHJvdG9jb2wiIElEPSJzMmYx ..
```

I have to replace `&#xd;&#xa;` by `%0D%0A`

Comment: I tried disabling the encoding option too but it didn't work. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the combination of the following JMeter Functions:

- [__unescapeHtml()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__unescapeHtml) - to convert these `&#xd;&#xa;` Unicode symbols into "normal" line breaks
- [__urlEncode()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__urlencode) - to convert line breaks into URL-escaped codes

Assuming you have JMeter Variable reference name `foo` you will need to combine these functions like:

```
${__urlencode(${__unescapeHtml(${foo})})}
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Functions Demo]

Check out [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) article to get familiarized with the JMeter Functions concept.